# MySQL how to avoid many joins in a complex sorting of a table?

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-order-by

Assume I have an existing table of "items", containing cities, states and countries distinguished by the field "type" which contains "City", "State" or "Country". A field "parent_id" of a city either points to a "State" entry or to a "Country" entry (if the country does not have states).

I have another table of "local_names" where some of the above items have corresponding local names, others don't.

I want to get all items ordered by their local name (or their "original" name if local is missing) in the order "City, Country" (also when state is available).

table items

```
id type    name         parent_id ...
 1 City    Detroit      2
 2 State   Michigan     3
 3 Country USA
 4 City    Cologne      5
 5 Country Germany
```

table local_names

```
id item_id name
 1      4  Koln
 2      5  Deutschland
```

Wanted result:

```
Detroit, USA
Koln, Deutschland
```

But the following performs quite poor. How could it be improved?

```
SELECT * FROM items
LEFT JOIN items AS parent ON parent.id = items.parent_id
LEFT JOIN items AS grandparent ON grandparent.id = parent.parent_id

LEFT JOIN local_names AS local_item_name ON local_item_name.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN local_names AS local_parent_name ON local_parent_name.item_id = parent.id
LEFT JOIN local_names AS local_grandparent_name ON local_grandparent_name.item_id = grandparent.id

ORDER BY coalesce(coalesce(local_grandparent_name.name, grandparent.name),
                  coalesce(local_parent_name.name, parent.name), 
                  coalesce(local_item_name.name, items.name)),
         coalesce(local_item_name.name, items.name)
```